# Issue with getting struct keys in Railo

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

Building an application with Railo and cfWheels.

I created a form with groups of radio buttons. Each group having the same name and the name being an array reference e.g (response[1]). There are 23 groups.

Each time I submit the form and I fetch the response array keys using either StructKeyList or StructKeyArray and eventually find the number of keys returned, I get 21.

I made a dump of the keys only to find out result of 2 groups are always combined.

I tried the same code with Adobe ColdFusion and it works fine. I get 23 responses with distinct values.

Comment: Please post the code. Railo and ACF can handle form values a bit differently, for example Railo handles name="foo[]" like array (PHP way).

Comment: Yes, please supply your relevant code.